# Ooyala Video not playing in any browser

Tags: ooyala

I followed steps in this site(http://support.ooyala.com/developers/users/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_tutorial.html)

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Ooyala Web Page 
    </title>
<script src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/50396e656f074f74828abeb517a52a46'>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='ooyalaplayer' style='width:640px;height:360px'></div>
    <script>OO.ready(function() { 
    window.player = OO.Player.create('ooyalaplayer', '03ZWZrdjqfMpvpYcC- _VNo7bsnDm78kO', {"autoplay":true}); });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What went wrong? The website has a container but video is not loaded its keep on giving the loading symbol

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still encountering this issue but I noticed a space in the movie id.

`window.player = OO.Player.create(
  'ooyalaplayer', 
  '03ZWZrdjqfMpvpYcC-_VNo7bsnDm78kO', 
  {"autoplay":true});
});`

When I remove the space the content does load, however it appears that the movie has expired.  The following error event was raised:

{"0":"error","1":{"code":"unknownSasContent","source":"flash"}}